# Task Runner in the .NET stack?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gruntjs, gulp

I've seen grunt in the MEANJS stack have a file watcher to automatically execute tasks such as moving around files when they change.  Is there anything like this in the .NET space, or am I better off installing node.js and adding grunt to my development stack?  I'm really looking to move .js/.css/.cshtml from my code repository to my wwwroot when they're edited and saved.

Comment: If you are considering using nodejs and gulp, I recently wrote about how you can do that in an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983027/automatically-switching-to-minified-css-js-files-in-different-environments/29989493#29989493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off adding Grunt to your development stack. You can then use the following extensions to add support in Visual Studio:
- [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708)
- [NPM and Bower package Intellisense](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/65748cdb-4087-497e-a394-2e3449c8e61e) 
- [Grunt Luncher](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff)

If you're on Mac you could use [CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) (not free). But still Grunt is highly recommended for what you're trying to achieve.

You might also want to experience with [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript) to watch your CSS/JS

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen grunt in the MEANJS stack have a file watcher to automatically execute tasks such as moving around files when they change. Is there anything like this in the .NET space

Yep, `FileSystemWatcher` in `System.IO` namespace [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)