# Automatically switching to minified CSS & JS files in different environments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 and also taking advantage of `WebEssentials LESS` and `bundle` features.

WebEssentials is setup to create minified css and js files on save.  This is a feature I want because I can monitor the output and it lowers the application startup time (*not using Asp.Net MVC bundles*).

**How can I automatically get my app to use the minified version of the files when it is deployed without having to manually change the file names?**

So, for example, from:

```
<link href="somestyles.css" .. >
```

to:

```
<link href="somestyles-min.css" .. >
```

I did read that I could combine WebEssentials and Asp.Net MVC Bundles, providing I disabled the minification option in Asp.Net MVC Bundles.  This would then substitute the MIN files in production (`web.config [debug="false"]`).

Is this my only option or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely not the only way. Another way would be to completely disconnect all Microsoft-based tools (ie bundling, web essentials, etc) and use a Javascript Task Runner. Then the compiling of supersets and pre-processers, minification and whatever other front-end heavy lifting can be in one place. It can also be based on the environment.

So let's address some of your specific concerns.

### Task running in the flavor of nodejs and gulp

1. Download [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/download/)
2. After downloading, open up a command prompt and navigate to your project source. For example:

   ```
   cd "C:\Users\beloud\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\YourProject"
   ```
3. Initialize a node project by running `npm init`. This will ask you a bunch of questions about your project. After completion, it will create a file, `package.json`, which will track your node dependencies and project details.
4. Now we need to install a few packages. In the command prompt, enter the following commands:

   ```
   npm install gulp -g 
   npm install gulp --save-dev
   npm install gulp-less --save-dev
   npm install gulp-minify-css --save-dev
   npm install gulp-if --save-dev
   ```

   We install gulp globally, so we can use it anywhere (it will add a path for you). Then we install a handful of packages locally to our project that will be doing that actual work (minifying, processing, etc).
5. Create a file in the same directory as your `package.json` named `gulpfile.js`.
6. Now we need to create our actual tasks. In `gulpfile.js`, add the following:

   ```
   //these are the modules that we'll be using in our task
   var gulp = require('gulp'),
       less = require('gulp-less'),
       gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
       minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

   var isDebug = true; // I usually have a config.js file that has this and some handy static paths that I'll be referencing regularly. Then I just require it above.
   gulp.task('default', function() {
     return gulp.src('Content/less/**/*.less')
       .pipe(less())
       .pipe(gulpif(isDebug === false, minifycss()))  //the first argument is the condition, the second is the method to call if the condition is true
       .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/css'));
   });
   ```
7. Run `gulp` in command prompt. That will run the `default` task. Basically, it will look for any less files in all directories under `Content/less`, compile them to css, minify them if `isDebug` is `false` and output it to `Content/css`.
8. Let's make it a little bit more awesome by adding a watch. Add the following to `gulpfile.js`:

   ```
   gulp.task('watch', function() {
     // Watch .less files
     gulp.watch('Content/less/**/*.less', ['default']);
   });
   ```

   Upon running gulp, the task will stay alive until manually terminated. It will watch for changes made to any less file in `Content/less` and will re-run the task upon saved changes.
9. Now, you just need to include the name of the css file as it will remain the same, regardless of the environment.

This is a very basic example of using a task runner to achieve what you're trying to do. You can do a whole lot more with nodejs, gulp and everything else I've referenced. I would personally suggest this because, it is way more powerful than the one-off tools you're currently using and Visual Studio 2015 is already heavily relying on this new methodology so you'll most likely have to learn this anyways.

You can learn more by following this really amazing tutorial, [Getting started with gulp](https://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/), by [Mark Goodyear](https://twitter.com/markgdyr).

Comment: I'm happy to hear how my answer can be improved if the downvoter will share why :)

Comment: I like this answer. just to add. WebEssentials no longer supports compiling of files in VS2015. Btw, if I have js files like jquery, foundation.js, react.js files. Is it advisable to combine them in one file like lib.min.js or its better to keep them separate and include them on html file line by line?

Comment: It depends on your end goal @Daskul.  Are all of the libs getting used on enough of your pages to solicit bundling? Are you making a ton of requests per page load? Questions like these should dictate whether you bundle or not.

Comment: Ok I get it, if Im sure that the libs are globally used or atleast majority of the pages then compile them in one file right? But when should I start to reconsider performance? I mean, how many page requests/sec or minute will start to be noticable?

Answer (score 0):

Grunt (and gulp) support is added in the next Visual studio. This is the javascript developers tools for doing the same thing - bundling for production.

Grunt can create a build version that is not minified for testing but minified for production. I might take some more time and effort but it is the future instead of the MS try they did with bundling. You can already use grunt if you have Node.js installed and be ready for the future.

There is plenty of [getting started resource](http://davidtucker.net/articles/automating-with-grunt/) out there. See also [Introducing Gulp, Grunt, Bower, and npm support for Visual Studio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx)

Comment: Visual studio is not required, you just need node.js installed and preinstalled with visual studio 2015 with some added integration.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this my only option or is there a better way to achieve this?

It's not your only option, but since you are working in the realm of MVC it's one of the better options.  Since it is designed to be leveraged at different levels, such as individual pages as well as layouts, it will take care of generating the appropriate link.

**In general, I would recommend you use a server side bundling framework oriented to MVC so that it can handle the link generation and gives you an intuitive API.**

SquishIt is an open-source framework that integrates well with MVC, and is also capable of being switched based on criteria such as a debug flag to generate the original source versus minified versions.

Both SquishIt and the new builtin MVC bundles are fairly similar in terms of what they are meant to accomplish.